# how to dynamically condition my className if pickTime === input value that will return active or null

Tags: reactjs

how to dynamically condition my className if pickTime === input value that will return active or null?\

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class FormTimePick extends Component {
  render() {
    const { pickTime } = this.props.values;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="form-time-pick-container">
          <div className="form-time-pick-morning">
            <h1>Morning</h1>
            <div className="form-time-pick-gird">
              <input
                className={pickTime === value ? "active" : null}
                name="pickTime"
                type="button"
                onClick={this.props.handleInputChange}
                value="8:00AM"
              />

              <input
                className={pickTime === pickTime ? "active" : null}
                name="pickTime"
                type="button"
                onClick={this.props.handleInputChange}
                value="8:30AM"
              />
          </div>
        </div>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.prevStep()}>back</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FormTimePick;
```

how to dynamically condition my className if pickTime === input value that will return active or null

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [clsx](https://github.com/lukeed/clsx) utility package for constructing className strings conditionally.

Using that we will get:

`className={clsx({active: pickTime === value})}`